# Adding new libraries in PyDev via windows->preferences

Tags: python, libraries

I would like to add the scipy library to be used in the PyDev App for Eclipse.  I have navigated my way to windows->preferences->Python->Interpreters->Python Interpreters->Libraries.  When I am here I click on "new egg/zip" but cannot locate the .egg file associated with scipy. I am able to locate the file holding all python libraries, but cannot seem to locate the .egg file within the scipy folder in the python libraries.  How can I locate the .egg file easily?

Thanks

Comment: as far as I know you could install it with `pip`, eclipse will recognize it

Comment: thx, I'll keep the pip route in mind.  I ended up using the add folder button and just dropped the search for the .egg altogether.